# Open files app directly in mobile devices

Tags: html

In mobile devices, I know that I can open the camera app directly by using: `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`. But I was wondering if we could open the files app directly too? Removing the `capture` attribute will prompt the user to take a new photo from the camera app or open an existing one in your local files. Though in my use case, I don't want to prompt for the camera app.

I tried researching on this but to no avail. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

With this input the file app opens and you get to choose any file that is an image:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work on Chrome Android and Safari iOS. It still prompts to choose from Camera and Files app.

Comment: In that case that is a setting on mobile devices and I don't think there is a way to do that in your html... however let me know if you find a way ;)